# SVG image with poor quality in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, svg, adobe-illustrator

I am pretty new with `SVG` images. I am trying to use SVG images in an Android Studio project. 
I have an SVG image that I created in Illustrator in my `raw` directory within my project.
I have also integrated a jar fie: svg-android.jar...
In my main activity I have this humble code:

```
package meaningless.safr.com.meaningless;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG;
import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create a new ImageView
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        // Set the background color to white
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        // Parse the SVG file from the resource
        SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.personaje);
        // Get a drawable from the parsed SVG and set it as the drawable for the ImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
        // Set the ImageView as the content view for the Activity
        setContentView(imageView);
    }
}
```

The SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!--<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">-->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon points="50,25.62 57.82,1.23 57.73,26.84 72.7,6.07 64.69,30.39 85.36,15.26 70.23,35.92 94.55,27.92 73.78,42.89 
    99.38,42.79 75,50.62 99.38,58.44 73.78,58.34 94.55,73.32 70.23,65.31 85.36,85.97 64.69,70.84 72.7,95.17 57.73,74.39 57.82,100 
    50,75.62 42.18,100 42.27,74.39 27.3,95.17 35.31,70.84 14.64,85.97 29.77,65.31 5.45,73.32 26.22,58.34 0.62,58.44 25,50.62 
    0.62,42.79 26.22,42.89 5.45,27.92 29.77,35.92 14.64,15.26 35.31,30.39 27.3,6.07 42.27,26.84 42.18,1.23 "/>
<polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="50,34.64 55,19.05 54.94,35.42 64.51,22.14 59.39,37.69 72.6,28.02 62.93,41.22 78.47,36.11 
    65.2,45.68 81.56,45.62 65.98,50.62 81.56,55.61 65.2,55.55 78.47,65.12 62.93,60.01 72.6,73.21 59.39,63.54 64.51,79.09 
    54.94,65.81 55,82.18 50,66.59 45,82.18 45.06,65.81 35.49,79.09 40.61,63.54 27.4,73.21 37.07,60.01 21.53,65.12 34.8,55.55 
    18.44,55.61 34.02,50.62 18.44,45.62 34.8,45.68 21.53,36.11 37.07,41.22 27.4,28.02 40.61,37.69 35.49,22.14 45.06,35.42 45,19.05 
    "/>
<circle fill="#110505" cx="50" cy="50" r="10.89"/>
<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="50" cy="50" r="8.71"/>
<circle fill="#E6007E" cx="50" cy="50" r="3.07"/>

</svg>
```

The code serves its function, to display the image on the device. Now, the problem is, the image appears to be in a poor quality even though its format is SVG. This is how the final output looks like:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I converted the SVG into XML. Now, I used it in my layout code as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="meaningless.safr.com.meaningless.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/personaje"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the final output:

[image]

It looks nice, just how I wanted it but I think I should be able to have the same result within the Java code using the image with the SVG file.

Thanks again.

Comment: **1** - The bunch of empty `<g></g>` don't seem to be functional. **2** - The SVG file becomes rasterized before being fed to the ImageView - check out the ImageView scaling. **3** - `setContentView(imageView);` gives me chills.

Comment: That's very weird. You SVG and code look alright. I can't think of a good explanation why only part of your SVG appears to have such low resolution. Are you absolutely sure that the SVG you provided is the exact same one you are using in your app?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand beyond point **1**...

Comment: Am positive, is the same SVG file.

Comment: What is wrong with `setContentView(imageView);`?

Comment: **2** - it's how the library works: it converts the SVG to a bitmap, then passes it to the ImageView. But if the ImageView is then scaled (i.e.: set to match_parent programmatically), the bitmap becomes stretched. **3** - It's not needed, since it should be already included in the contentView you set here: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` (why do you create it at runtime?!). **2** and **3** are possibly working against you. Solution: use an ImageView (it becomes scaled **before** you assign it the converted SVG, which now gets converted to the right scaling factor) in the main layout.

Comment: Which seems right what you have done. You just made another step: converting to a VectorDrawable. And this now makes the SVG library no longer used.

Comment: Rotwang is incorrect. It is not creating a bitmap then passing it to the ImageView. It is creating a `PictureDrawable` which is a recording of the Android `Canvas` calls used when rendering the SVG file. Rotwang also doesn't explain why part of the picture is at a lower resolution than the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is has any connection to the cause of your problem, but there is one slightly odd thing about your code.  It is point 3 of Rotwang's first comment.

First you are setting a layout to be content of your Activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

then you are replacing it with an ImageView

```
setContentView(imageView);
```

Normally you would have an ImageView in your layout. You would then get the ImageView using its `id` and set the drawable into that.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create a new ImageView
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) fiindViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    // Set the background color to white
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    // Parse the SVG file from the resource
    SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.personaje);
    // Get a drawable from the parsed SVG and set it as the drawable for the ImageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
}
```

Comment: The image is still low quality... Thanks.